# How to deal with routing when developing a custom CMS in Codeigniter

Tags: php, url, codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-url

I’m a recent user of Codeigniter and am developing a simple backend CMS to manage pages.

Based on a URL (in this example I have hidden “index.php”) : mysite.com/pagename

I would like the system to detect if there is a value of “pagename” in my database, if there is, I need the system to re-route to a custom controller (eg: Pagemaker) and if there is no record called pagename, just do it’s normal thing (i.e. find a controller called pagename)

Currently I have:

```
$route['(:any)'] = "pagemaker/create/$1";
```

whereby all requests are forwarded to my custom function.

However I want to change this structure so that if the page does NOT exist in the db, the traditional codeigniter request process is followed.

**Can anyone offer any advice about how to complete this? Or any advice about routing custom CMS’s in codeigniter in general?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to [upgrade to CI 2.0](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/news/2010/05/upgrading-to-codeigniter-2.0) because [it's stable enough](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/news/2010/10/codeigniter-2.0-is-stable) and it gives you plenty of useful features.

In your case, set the following route:

```
$route['404_override'] = 'pagemaker';
```

If the router doesn't know where to go it just goes to pagemaker controller. This can then check if the first uri segment exists and if not you create a custom 404 page instead of the crappy default one.

And I don't want to hear any of this "Oh but it's not released yet" crap, I've been using it CI 2.0 for almost a year. ;-)

Comment: OK I'm going to upgrade... I'm scared. Hold me Phil ;-)

Comment: Fine, but keep your hands to yourself.

Comment: just a quick question: why is this route not mentioned in the user guide which ships with ci 2.0?

Comment: If anyone comes across this in the future, the discussed route: $route['404_override'] must contain both a controller and a method i.e in my example : $route['404_override'] = 'pagemaker/create'   it will not work otherwise

Comment: This was fixed in CodeIgniter Reactor and will most likely be fixed in Core soon.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two possibilities:

1) Edit your custom function to let it redirect your client when page's not in the db
pseudo code:

```
if($dbresult == null){
    redirect("http://yoursite.com/"+$this->uri->segment(3));
}
```

2) Edit the router class of CI so it will first check if the page's in the db and if not, just continues. This may be somewhat messier as you need a db connection in your Router.php

Comment: the problem with this is that your system is constantly going in a loop - redirecting back to the same pagemaker class every time and wont work.